# Poetry add dependency to package in non-standard apt-get repository

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-poetry

Is it possible to use poetry to include a dependency to a package that's installed via `apt-get` from a non-standard repository? Specifically I'm trying to add [ParselTongue](https://www.jive.eu/jivewiki/doku.php?id=parseltongue:parseltongue) as a dependency, but this requires adding a repository to apt-get to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kettenis-w/parseltongue
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-parseltongue
```

Is this possible with poetry?

Answer (score 1):

Poetry can handle only python package repositories like PyPi. So it is not possible to handle dependencies in a linux distribution repo.